# After click on UIAlertView header section of UITable was update from database in Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying create an App in which, I create `add button` in table.m file on navigation bar when i press `button` the alert view open. <kbd>Enter name of alert title.</kbd> This alert title store in database and this title show on UITableView. How to show?

```
-(IBAction)Add:(id)sender
{
    UIAlertView *myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"GPS Reminder?" message:@"Please Enter Reminder" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];

    text_field = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12.0, 45.0, 260.0, 25.0)];
    text_field.placeholder=@"Enter Reminder";
    [text_field becomeFirstResponder];
    [text_field setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [myAlertView addSubview:text_field];
    [myAlertView show];

}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex;
{
     if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        [self validation];

        NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into Worklist (userid,worktype) values ('%d','%@')",pkoflist,text_field.text];
        NSLog(@"%@",str);

        [Database executeQuery:str];
        [self initilization];
    }
}
```

Comment: "enter name of alert title"? what is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mistake in my void method and i detect this one....
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex;
{

```
if (buttonIndex == 1)
{
    if([self validation])
    {
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into Worklist (userid,worktype) values ('%d','%@')",pkoflist,text_field.text];
    NSLog(@"%@",str);

    [Database executeQuery:str];
    [self initilization];
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can't give a alert to text field. When you click on it you can assign it to a button. See the code to make `otherButtonTitles` as `nil`.

```
-(void)method {
     UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"username" 
                                   message:@"plz enter the corret username" 
                                  delegate:nil 
                         cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                         otherButtonTitles: nil];
     [alert show];
     [alert release];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the alertViewStyle UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"title" message:@"message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Abort" otherButtonTitles:@"Save", nil];
alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
[alert show];
```

then in

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
   if (buttonIndex == 1) {
    // get string from textfield
    string = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text;
    // save
    // reload table with saved string
}
```